# YouCompleteMe: do I have to install extra plugins for semantic completion?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

Looking at the docs for [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) it relies on other plugins to do semantic completion for a lot of the languages it has.

#### Example for python from the docs:

> YCM relies on the Jedi engine to provide completion and code navigation. By default, it will pick the version of Python running the ycmd server and use its sys.path. While this is fine for simple projects, this needs to be configurable when working with virtual environments or in a project with third-party packages. The next sections explain how to do that.

Does this mean that I need to have [Jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/usage.html) installed?

What I'm really getting at is does [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) come with these semantic plugins or do they need to be installed seperately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you need to [install](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/installation.html#installation-and-configuration) Jedi separately.

In case you have multiple instances of Python installed on your machine,
[Here](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#python-semantic-completion) are some information from the YouCompleteMe site to help you to install it correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see your edition. Could you review it? Feel free to ask another question too. Atomic questions are better, they have more chance to get multiple answers and to be reused by others :-)

Comment: This ‘accepted’ answer is categorically incorrect YCM will NOT use a Jedi installed separately. 

I’m the YCM maintainer.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt perhaps you could chime in on: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/43410/are-there-any-good-vim-plugins-to-use-which-might-not-be-well-known

Comment: @puremourning also interest to hear your thoughts on: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/43410/are-there-any-good-vim-plugins-to-use-which-might-not-be-well-known

Comment: Vimspector, obviously

Answer (score 5):

No, Jedi is bundles with YCM. Just use the installer per its documentation.

Comment: After coming to your channels, I got the right answer. I got confused reading the docs one part says that ycm requires Jedi engine. Then in another part it says that for your supported languages they all come with their respective engines. Should've been more patient.